# How to correctly console.log response from fetch api using async and await?

Tags: javascript, fetch

How do you console.log the response from the fetch API when using async and await so that you can use dot notation to access certain data from the response to update HTML elements?

```
const url = "/api/contact"
uploadFile = async () => {
    try {
        const config = {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        }
        const response = await fetch(url, config)
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log(response) // does not give the json data needed to update html elements
            return response
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong. Try again.")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
uploadFile()
```

Comment: `uploadFile().then(response => /* do stuff with the response */)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response object has a `.json()` function that you returns another `Promise` with the result being the deserialized JSON from the response body as a JavaScript object.